# Login to SQL Server with "sa" just possible after changing password

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange problem. In SQL Server Management Studio 18, I tried to log in with the `sa` account. It failed.

I know in this case we should check mixed mode auth and `sa` enable checkbox. I checked them and they were enabled. I saw all the net for other checkboxes or something useful but nothing that not enabled for me.

I logged in with Windows auth and changed the password of sa. after changing, sa login worked. but few minutes later after some tests with my application, I realized that I can't login remotely to sa. I returned and check again in management studio and While it was unbelievable, the sa login failed again.
I changed sa password and the story repeated again. what was happening?

Comment: Sounds like someone else is changing the password of the `sa`. Logging in wouldn't just "stop working".

Comment: Disable the SA account and create a dedicated application and/or user login with appropriate permissions. The first thing I do on a new SQL instance is kill SA as it's a prime attack surface.

Comment: @StuartFrankish Thanks man. It works. If you want, post your comment in individual answer to select for best answer.

Answer (score -1):

Note, while this doesn't directly resolve a problem experienced with the SA account, which is ultimately unknowable without extensive investigation into the specific host environment, it does form part of best practice which the OP has identified as having resolved their overall problem.

The original comment:

> Disable the SA account and create a dedicated application and/or user
>   login with appropriate permissions. The first thing I do on a new SQL
>   instance is kill SA as it's a prime attack surface.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24877524)

Comment: @SoumyaMohan - The issue with the SA account could be down to any number of factors that it's impossible to cover in a single answer. My comment (read the comments) resolves the issue by providing best practice which the OP has identified as having resolved their overall problem.